# Cannot access memory

Tags: c, gdb, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segfault, and when I debug it I get the following message:

Cannot access memory at 0x806d128

I attempted to set a watchpoint there to monitor the address, but the response gdb gave me was:

> Cannot watch constant value '0x806d128'

However when I print the pointer containing the address it recognises the struct that I've got stored there:

> (body *) 0x806d128

According to gdb the error occurs in `addForce()`, which is a bit odd since that address is accessed earlier in `init()`

Here's the relevant code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define prec float

prec gdt = 0.0001;

typedef struct {
  float Fx, Fy, vx, vy, mass;
  int posX, posY;
} body;


void addForce(body* a, body* b){
  int xa=(*a).posX, ya=(*a).posY;
  int xb=(*b).posX, yb=(*b).posY;
  float F=(*a).mass * (*b).mass * gdt /(pow(xa-xb, 2)+pow(ya-yb, 2));
  float v=atan((ya-yb)/(xa-xb));
  float Fx=cos(v)/F, Fy=sin(v)/F;
  (*a).Fx+=Fx;
  (*a).Fy+=Fy;
  (*b).Fx-=Fx;
  (*b).Fy-=Fy;
}


int newRandInt(int bot, int top){
  return bot + (rand() % (top++));
}

prec newRand() 
{
    prec r = (prec)((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
    return r;
}


void init(int N, body* star){
  for(int i=0; i<N;i++){
    star[i].posX = newRandInt(0, 800);
    star[i].posY = newRandInt(0, 800);

    star[i].Fx = newRand();
    star[i].Fy = newRand();

    star[i].vx = newRand();
    star[i].vy = newRand();

    star[i].mass = newRand();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int N = 200;

body* stars = malloc(sizeof(body)*N);

init(N, stars);
for(int j1=0; j1<N; j1++){
  for(int j2=0; j2<N-1; j2++){
    if(j1!=j2){
      addForce(stars+sizeof(body)*j1, stars+sizeof(body)*j2);
    }
  }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: This code won't compile.

Comment: which is kinda sad, as we don't see how you call `init`.

Comment: What's stars? Can't find it anywhere but you call addForce with it as argument. I have strong feeling there should be star called instead of stars.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just copied parts of the document. I can take the entire thing and make the irrelevant parts comments if you wish.

Comment: *delete* the irrelevant parts. *all* of them. then make sure it compiles, and reproduces the problem. (and perhaps do some debugging? :))

Comment: Sorry guys. Now it compiles and the bug remains exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call to `addForce` is not what you want:

```
addForce(stars+sizeof(body)*j1, stars+sizeof(body)*j2);
```

You don't want the `sizeof(body)` expression in this call to `addForce`. The call you probably want is:

```
  addForce(stars+j1, stars+j2);
```

`stars` is an array of `body` so you can reference individual stars with

```
body *p = &stars[i]
```

or just

```
body *p = stars + i
```

Both of these have the type body*

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
addForce(stars+sizeof(body)*j1, stars+sizeof(body)*j2);
```

when you do `sizeof(body)` it evaluates to size of structure in bytes, then it is multiplied by `j1`. So you have `some_nr*j1`.
That value is `added` to stars, which is pointer to body.
Pointer arithmetics evaluate `some_nr*j1*sizeof(pointer to body)`.
What you want to do is `stars+j1` alone, which will be correctly evaluated as pointer to body and added to arrays.
The same happends in the second part of addForce.
What you missed is that with pointers arithmetics the second operand of '+' operator is recalculated to match size of pointee.